# How to change text in html with either JS, PHP or HTML on load?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm doing this sort of a dictionary which by now works but I have few more things to edit which I have problems with.

It is a simple page with basic editing. The only more complicated stuff is the search and functioning of the button which is done.

I have 4 different languages, Italian, French, German with Italian as default and English.

I also have a simple "Dizionario IBS" (Italian) welcome like thingy but I want that everytime I change languages (Language change is basically a filter, it switches the search result that comes up after you write inside the search bar) the "Dizionario IBS" switches text to more appropriate like if I were to click on "English" Button which filter search results to english the "Dizionario IBS" would become "IBS Dictionary".

I have tried to change it with JS, PHP and HTML, looked up codes and such here but none of them worked.

I'm very basic in programming so I barely know these languages, I'm sorry if I seem too inexperienced.

I also tried to change the type of the text I want changed, like I made it into a `input type = text` `readonly` and `<h1>like this</h1>` and tried to see if that would make things work.

Any suggestions?

```
<div id='header'>
    <img id='img' src='logo.jpg'>
    <div id='header-testo'>
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="submit" id="myButton" name="lingua" value="English" />
            <input type="hidden" name="linguaa" value="en" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id='header-test'>
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="submit" id="myButton" name="lingua" value="Fran&#231ais" />
            <input type="hidden" name="linguaa" value="fr" />

        </form>
    </div>
    <div id='header-test'>
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="submit" id="myButton" name="lingua" value="Deutsch" />
            <input type="hidden" name="linguaa" value="de" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id='header-test'>
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="submit" id="myButton" name="lingua" value="Italiano" />
            <input type="hidden" name="linguaa" value="it" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='body'>
    <h1 id="titolo">Dizionario IBS</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="searchBar" name="search" placeholder="" value="" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
        <input type="submit" id="searchBtn" value="Vai!" />
        <input type="hidden" name="linguaa" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The hidden input is the one that filters the search bar via language, dunno if it's relevant but just saying.

The whole thing works, but I want that every time I click and filter language, the `"titolo"` text changes to the said language as well.

JS code suggested by a user:

```
<div id='body'>
                <h1 id="titolo"></h1>
                <script>
                    var heading = document.getElementById('titolo');
                    function languagechange(id) {
                        if (id == '') {
                            heading.textContent = 'Dizionario IBS';
                        } else if (id == 'english') {
                            heading.textContent = 'IBS Dictionary';
                        } else if (id == 'french') {
                            heading.textContent = 'IBS Dictionnaire';
                        } else if (id == 'italian') {
                            heading.textContent = 'Dizionario IBS';
                        } else if (id == 'german') {
                            heading.textContent = 'IBS W\u00F6rterbuch';
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <br>
                <br> <br> <br>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="text" id="searchBar" name="search" placeholder="" value="" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" autofocus /><input type="submit" id="searchBtn" value="Vai" />
                    <input type ="hidden" name="linguaa" />
                </form>
        </div>
```

I moved the JS below the title becuase If i remember correctly putting it above didn't show anything. Also the first "if" was to try to set italian as default to always show when loading the page, didn't work however.

Comment: Please post the code you mentioned that works already. It will make it easier to help you extend it to include the additional functionality.

Comment: Actually I tried various ways, as I've said I looked up the codes on similar cases but most of them ended up being JQuery and those that weren't didn't work. Some methods were making a function. In that case it "printed" the name of the function, ignoring the code. I tried to then do it with document.GetElementById("titolo").innerHTML = "text"; That sort of worked but it only did on the last example in the order, so Italian, it compleately ignored the other languages on click of the button or not. I also tried window.onload but that didn't work either. Honestly I have no idea what to do.

Comment: That "sort of worked" code would have been a good starting point to post. Either way i'm sure you get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things that you need to amend which I have mentioned steps wise below:

1) Firstly, change all your input type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` ONLY under the `id='header'` forms. Otherwise every time you click the button it **submits** the form. Or if you want the form to function then prevent it from submitting. As I do not see any need for the language buttons to have a form, I suggest to change the type to `button`

2) Many elements in your markup has the same `id` value. This is bad. `id` attribute should be unique to each element in a DOM.

3) Coming to your solution, add a `onclick` event to your button like so & pass the unique `id` of the clicked button using `this.id`.

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="button" id="english" name="lingua" value="English" onclick="languagechange(this.id);" />
    <input type="hidden" name="linguaa" value="en" />
</form>
```

Then in your JavaScript declare the `languagechange()` function like so & compare the `id` passed earlier to determine the language & change the text accordingly

```
var heading = document.getElementById('titolo');

function languagechange(id) {
  if(id == 'english') {
    heading.textContent = "English text";  
  } else if(id == 'french') {
    heading.textContent = "French text";  
  }
}
```

Comment: The same id value is to simply edit in CSS that they have the same font size, border, etc. As I said I'm fairly new so I don't understand why should I make multiple ID's in this case since they would pretty much be the same. Also, how would I connect the input onclick with the <h1 id="titolo"> </h1> ?

Comment: That is exactly why **classes** are used for. Always remember `class` are used to mention common styles etc. `id` should be always used for functionalities. I already mentioned in my answer how to connect them using `document.getElementById('titolo').textContent = "French text"`. Read my asnwer.

Comment: Had to delete two comments, first one was me not reading the whole thing and second i thought everything worked. Now I got two issues. if I set type="button" it doesn't filter the languages in the search bar, meaning every record shows up instead of only those tagged as english or italian etc. if i leave it at type="submit" the filter works fine but the suggesting you gave me with JavaScript dissapears after I click on it, like it shows for half a second then stops. Suggestions?

Comment: Where did you change the `type="button"` ? In the SearchBtn ? Also could you give me the JS code for filtering

Comment: I changed every submit as you suggested to button. I'll put the JS finished code in the question.

Comment: Every submit EXCEPT the SearchBtn. If you read my first point I have mentioned, "**change all your input type from type="submit" to type="button" ONLY under the `id='header` forms.**"

Comment: yeah that's what i didn't only for the language, not the SearchBtn

Comment: I mean is there any JS code when you click on the searchBtn ? any filtering related JScode. You have posted the same script I gave you. I want to know how does your Search work

Comment: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/37QL here's the entire code so far the search works through php

Comment: There are 2 version of the `name` atribute, one is `name="lingua"`(in all the language buttons) & the other is `name="linguaa"`(in all hidden). Is there any reason for 2 different names ?

Comment: the hidden one has the value that is used to filter things, but I actually found how to resolve this, i've been suggested to use entiierly PHP for this  language change and keeping the filther working. This is the code if you want to see, i tested and it seems to work http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/37QR

Comment: Thanks in any case, learned quite a bit about JavaScript, at least way more than i knew before.

Comment: Awesome...Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

$(document).ready(function() { $("#titolo").val('Put anything you want');});

try with jquery

onload, this command will change the text in the element 'titolo' with whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you but I asked if it's possible to do in JS, PHP or HTML, I don't even know what's Jquery, seen some things but never used or learned. In any case I think i almost found a solution thanks to another user

Comment: Jquery is just a library of javascript!

Comment: In the future you will understand how easy is to use it instead of javascript.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will help you https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide

If u use angular translate your html will look like this

```
<div id='body'>
<h1 id="titolo">{{'IBS' | translate}}</h1>
```

And then u just set up a file for each language with the translation.

Italiano would be

```
# suppress inspection "UnusedProperty" for whole file
IBS=Dizionario IBS
```

English would be

```
# suppress inspection "UnusedProperty" for whole file
IBS= IBS Directory
```

Afterwards you just need to write a function which selects which file is used if you press the button

U really should take a look at the doc

Comment: Thats an intresting one but i think it's a bit complicated for my level, not that the command seems difficult, just not something I have saw or heard about. I almost have found a solution that works, thank you anyhow.